# Microsoft BotBuilder nodejs Tutorial Error

Tags: node.js, botframework

everyone
I try to follow the [tutorial](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/overview/) to build my first bot.

But when I use [Bot Framework Emulator](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/tools/bot-framework-emulator/) to connect it, It don't show Hello World on Emulator.

And when I send some thing word(like 'test' or 'P') to server, It crash can show me

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5631
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1045:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1090:14)
```

how can i fix it?

Comment: Please share the code that you've worked on so we can help you fix the error :)

Comment: Are you running with Administrator privileges your debugger (I assumed Visual Studio Code)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I use ngrok to connect my local applicaion.
I don't know why I can't connect it without ngrok.
But It just can work, Thanks everyone ^^

Answer (score 0):

You fill in the right values under the following section:

```
var connector = new builder.ChatConnector({
    appId: process.env.MICROSOFT_APP_ID,
    appPassword: process.env.MICROSOFT_APP_PASSWORD
});
```

MICROSOFT_APP_ID and MICROSOFT_APP_PASSWORD should be 'undefined' or filled properly by registering a new bot under:
[Microsoft Bot Framework](https://dev.botframework.com/)

Also, I see that you are trying to connect using port 5631 instead of 3986 - Make sure to check the right port is set when creating the server:

```
server.listen(process.env.port || process.env.PORT || 3978, function () {
    console.log('%s listening to %s', server.name, server.url); 
});
```

Comment: Working with the Emulator does not require entering MICROSOFT_APP_ID and MICROSOFT_APP_PASSWORD. But definitely the port, on which the server is running on, should be checked .

Comment: I use the currect MICROSOFT_APP_ID and MICROSOFT_APP_PASSWORD

and the port is Emulator generate